# Qt Creator - uic not being automatically run on build

Tags: c++, qt

I'm a bit new to Qt but I'm following along a couple of books for it. The books make it sound like when I build in Qt Creator or run `qmake myproject.pro` that `uic` is supposed to automatically run in order to convert my `.ui` to `.h`. But it just isn't happening. I haven't seen `uic` run once in all the example projects that I've been doing. I've had to use the Qt Command Prompt to invoke uic manually each time I change the `.ui`.

All the software is installed with default parameters. Is there someplace in Qt Creator where I need to specify the path to `uic` or something?

Comment: hmmm...try reinstalling the QtSDK.  This should be happening automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You may have forgotten to include your ui file in the FORMS variable.

Comment: When I add the .ui file into my project in Qt Creator, do I need to manually edit the .pro file to add it as well? I have not been doing that, I assumed adding a file to a project did that for me...

Comment: For me all .ui files where added autmatically to the FORMS variable. But when I change one, even if I manually run qmake, uic is not executed on F5.